# How to detect close in another domain of iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

My webpage has a iframe.

And click button, form submit to a iframe with POST method, another domain.

```
<iframe name="iframe" src=""> </iframe>

<form name="form" target="iframe" action="another domain" method="POST">
 ... 
</form>

document.form.submit();
```

In the iframe, Another domain close window.

How to detect that?

I use `iframe.contentWindow`, but `iframe.contentWindow.document.head` raise error in Internet Explorer because access denied.

Comment: You cannot access content in an iframe if that content comes from a different domain.

Comment: Please define "_close window_" in case of an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime along time ago, it was possible.
But now these days where security on the internet has become important you can no longer modify inside an iframe.

since iframe.contentWindow is readonly i simply think what you are trying to do is impossible to do what you want.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow

anyways posting data from client side code to another domain can be considered unsafe and might give you problems.
Also HTTP/Form POST is unencrypted, and unsafe for transmitting personal info, so i will urge you to use SSL and also to think about what you send.